# Macbook Pro Early 2011 max ram support

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, memory

Is it possible to put in 16 Gb ( 8 + 8 ) 1333 Mhz DDR3 in Macbook pro 15 Early 2011? As o apple website it says 8Gb max support, but I have found via Google Search, that people are using 16Gb also.

Thanks

Comment: Apple reference is at: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201165#1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MacBook Pro from early 2011 will support 16GB of ram. The Macbook Pro 15" (non-retina) were sold with a maximum upgradeable ram of 8GB from the factory. However you can check OWC with your exact model number and confirm that it supports 16Gb.

OWC states the models that support 16GB here: http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/memory/Apple_MacBook_MacBook_Pro/Upgrade/DDR3_1333MHz_SDRAM

To get your exact model id follow those steps: (Lion instructions also apply for mountain lion)

[image: how to find your model id]

Comment: Just out of interest, why would Apple show less RAM than possible?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I believe at the time you couldn't get 4GB in a single chip--the max was 2GB.

Comment: @Buscar웃: they show the maximum you could get factory-installed, which was 8GB.

Comment: @houbysoft that would not make sense since Apple would make more money by offering it as option.

Comment: @Buscar웃: they don't even offer 16GB today on the regular mbpro today... I'm sure they had somebody calculate what makes sense and what doesn't for them.